# Why does $2\pi$ divided by the number of sides of a polygon give a regular polygon?

Tags: geometry, circles, pi

If I have $2\pi/n$, where $n$ is the number of sides of a polygon, does the answer give me a length of sides necessary for me to draw the polygon with those $n$ sides as a regular polygon inside the circle?

I know it works or I believe it does.  But analytically, without anything but the drawing, how can I know this is true?  I am having trouble visualizing it.  I want to know why it works.

Comment: @Aweygan I do not understand.  Number is the number of sides of a polygon.  The result is supposed to be a regular polygon that I can fit in a circle.  It is assuming I want to get a regular polygon.

Comment: If someone is going to downvote me please help me understand how to better ask it.

Comment: @johnny When you divide $2\pi$ by the number of sides (or any other number), you get a number, like 0.314.  Your first question is asking "why does 0.314 give me a regular polygon?"  The answer is it doesn't: a number by itself does not give you a polygon.  You need to describe what you are doing with that number to obtain a polygon from it.

Comment: @Aweygan I changed it.

Comment: @ErickWong I want to draw a polygon inside a circle that is a regular polygon.  I read somewhere that you can get the correct length of the sides for that polygon by dividing the number of sides of that polygon by 2*pi.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720935/historic-proof-of-the-area-of-a-circle/1678093#1678093

Comment: @johnny Thanks, that clarifies a lot.  One thing still missing is how large your circle is.  Clearly the size of the circle determines the length of the side.  And is it the straight-line length you are measuring, or the arc length?

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is divide the angle at the center of the circle by $n$, which gives angles of $\frac {2 \pi}n$ radians at the center. Now draw radii from the center to the circle at this spacing and make the points where the radii hit the circle.  As all the central angles are the same, the lengths of the sides between the radii are all the same.  The angles between the sides of your polygon are twice the base angle of the isoceles triangles formed by the radii, so the angles are all the same.  This proves this gives a regular polygon.

The lengths of the side will scale with the radius of the circle.  For a [regular polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon) of $n$ sides in a circle of radius $r$, the side will be $s=2r \sin \frac {\pi}n$, which you can prove by looking at the isoceles triangles.

Comment: @johnny When $r=1$ and $n$ is very large, then $2r \sin \frac{\pi}n$ will be very close to $2\pi/n$, but it will never be exactly equal no matter how big $n$ is.

Comment: thanks for this awesome answer, could you add a quick schema for the sake of future reader please?