# Two definitions of $\pi$

Tags: geometry, math-history, pi

I have the feeling that ancient mathematicians (like Greek or Chinese), trying to find good approximations of $\pi$ used two definitions:

- If $A$ is the area of a disk and $r$ is its radius, $\pi=A/r^2$
- If $\ell$ is the length of a circle and $d$ is its diameter, $\pi=\ell/d$

Had they a proof that these definitions are of the same number?

Comment: This question belongs on hsm.se, but I presume they used [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fb/CircleArea.svg) to explain why the circumference being $2\pi r$ implies the area is $\pi r^2$. Update: no, Archimedes used [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_of_a_circle#Archimedes's_proof) instead. See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720935/historic-proof-of-the-area-of-a-circle) question.

Comment: @J.G.Aren't they basically the same?

Comment: IMO, Ancient Greeks do not think at a "constant" (they do not named it). See [Archimedes' *Measurement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_of_a_Circle) : they proved that $A=\dfrac 1 2 (\ell r)$ and calculated approximations for the *ratio* $\mathcal \ell : d$. But this *ratio* was **not** a number for ancient Greeks.

Comment: Maybe useful : AJEM Smeur, [On the Value Equivalent to pi in Ancient Mathematical Texts, (AHES, 1970)](http://users.uoa.gr/~apgiannop/Sources/Smeur-on-the-value-of-pi-in-ancient-mathematical-texts.pdf). See also [Pi: A Source Book](https://books.google.it/books?id=QhbrBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA677).